# Do words such as "could have", "should have", or "might have" represent the past possibilities of the past?

Tags: grammar, tense, time-reference, could-modal

We know that words such as **could have**, **should have**, or **might have** mean past possibilities.

When they are used in a noun clause following a verb, do they represent the past possibilities of the past?

**Examples I came up with:**

> (1) I thought he might have gone to gym.

=> Does it mean "go to gym" happened earlier than "I think"?

> (2) I told her that her sister could have gone on a date with a boy.

=> Does it mean "go on a date with a boy" happened earlier than "I tell her"?

---

If they represent the past of a past time, can I add time verbs?

> (a) I told her **yesterday** that her sister could have gone on a date with a boy **on July 24th, 2020**.

Comment: (1) Presumably the speaker is looking for someone who isn't there. "I thought (the reason he wasn't at home was) that he had gone to the gym."

Comment: (2) could mean something similar (the sister was absent because she had gone out on a date), or that she had had the opportunity to go at some time in the past, but didn't.

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry, I am quite stupid. Do you mean that parts following "might have" and "could have" are talking about things that happened earlier than the main verbs "thought" and "told", right? Can I use time verbs like in (a)? Can you answer that question also? Thank you.

Comment: I knocked on his door. He wasn't there. I thought he might have gone to the gym. (I thought that the reason he wasn't at home then might be that he had already left for the gym.) I don't know what situation you are imagining for your Sentence 2, but one meaning could be that the sister was absent and the speaker suggested that she might have gone out on a date. Does that make it any clearer? Your sentence (a) seems to imply the other meaning of (2). _Yesterday_ is an adverb, but you can use that or a date if you wish.